# How to skip the loop for last row of matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I am developing an angular crud app using AngularMaterial.

I want to skip the execution of last row for ***matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"** in below code as that row contains actions(edit/delete).

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-loading-shade"
       *ngIf="isLoadingResults">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResults"></mat-spinner>
  </div>
  <div class="button-row">
    <a mat-flat-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['/user-add']"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></a>
  </div>
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="example-table"
           matSort matSortActive="first_name" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="asc">

      <!-- User Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.userId}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- User Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>First Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.firstName}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="middleName">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Middle Name</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.middleName}}</td>
        </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Last Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.lastName}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="mobileNo">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Phone Number</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.mobileNo}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>E-Mail</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.email}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><mat-card-actions>
              <a mat-flat-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['/user-edit', row.userId]"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></a>
              <a mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="deleteUser(row.userId)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></a>
            </mat-card-actions></td>
        </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [routerLink]="['/user-details/', row.userId]"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

routing "/user-details" should not set for **ng-container "actions"**. Right now routing value "/user-details" is being set for actions and click function in **delete icon** is not functioning.

I have tried to separate actions from displayedColumns but edit/delete buttons should present in all rows. so this approach doesn't work.

Please help on what needs to be done to fix this.

================================================================

**Updated query :**

I noticed one strange thing and i don't know it is the expected behaviour or not.

```
deleteUser(id) {
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.api.deleteUser(id)
      .subscribe(res => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.router.navigate(['/users']);
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
        }
      );
  }
```

I have tried two cases for below delete link.

```
<a mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="deleteUser(row.userId)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></a>
```

case 1: with routerLink in mat-row

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [routerLink]="['/user-details/', row.userId]"></tr>
```

On selection of delete button function `deleteUser` got triggered, entry successfully deleted from db and page got refreshed (navigated to /users..... this.router.navigate(['/users']);).

case 2: with out routerLink in mat-row

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" ></tr>
```

On selection of delete button function `deleteUser` got triggered, entry successfully deleted from db but page didn't get refreshed and deleted entry is still showing.

`deleteUser` function is same in both cases but `this.router.navigate(['/users'])` was not executed in case 2. I am wondering why??

Comment: If you remove this row, your table stops working. Instead use `$event.preventDefault()` or `$event.stopPropagation()` on your actions to stop the propagation of the event, and prevent routing.

Comment: You use `user.userId` instead of `row.userId`. I don't see anything wrong with your approach apart from that. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Thanks @Mic . Yes, I used user.userId instead of row.userId . That was my bad. I fixed that later and delete button is working fine. One issue left is : I don't want to set RouterLink for actions column, so trying to skip the last element in displayedColumns . displayedColumns: string[] = ['userId', 'firstName', 'middleName', 'lastName', 'mobileNo', 'email', 'actions'];

Comment: I have updated the sample code with row.userId.

Comment: @trichetriche , Thank you for your reply. I am not sure this approach $event.preventDefault() or $event.stopPropagation()  fix my issue.

Comment: Given that i faced the same issue and it resolved it, I'm pretty sure it does. Best way to know is to try.

Comment: Hi @trichetriche , I tried it did not prevent routing instead delete is not working (on selection of delete button it is routing to user-details).

Comment: [Then you have some real explaining to do](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wkvche?file=app/table-basic-example.html), or you really need to be honest.

Comment: I have one more query added the details in updated query section in question. please check if you are able to help. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Hi @trichetriche, thanks for providing that link. there is no need to be dishonest. :)   I made mistake by adding $event.preventDefault(); at the first line of the deleteUser function. Now tried it by  adding at the end as follows, it worked fine .                                                                deleteUser(id, $event) {
    ...........................(..);
      $event.preventDefault();
  }